# MySQL ORDER BY id, but keep identical names next to each other

Tags: mysql, order-by

Suppose I have the following table:

```
id  name
---------
1   lion
2   tiger
3   lion
4   bear
5   tiger
6   bear
```

I would like to be able to return results with the most recent `id` column first, but keep all of the names together, like this:

```
id  name
---------
6   bear
4   bear
5   tiger
2   tiger
3   lion
1   lion
```

Is there a simple `ORDER BY` clause that can do this? Or do I have to do a UNION of some type?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an ordering based on the maximum id for name. Here's one attempt:

```
select id, name 
from animals x 
order by (select max(id) from animals y where x.name = y.name) desc
    , id desc;
```

It might be easier to understand if the derived column is explicit, and then order by that:

```
select id, name 
from (
    select id, name
         , (select max(id) 
            from animals y 
            where x.name = y.name
           ) as max_id 
    from animals x 
) as t 
order by max_id desc, id desc;
```

You could also use a join to a derived table, instead of the correated subquery:

```
select x.id, x.name 
from animals x
    join
       (select name, max(id) as max_id 
        from animals
        group by name
       ) y 
    on x.name = y.name
order by y.max_id desc, x.id desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here another possible solution..
using join

```
select t2.id,t2.name
from test t join test t2 on t2.name = t.name
group by t2.id order by max(t.id) desc, t2.id desc;
```

sqlfiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/826272/23

Comment: **[Discussion moved to chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76698/discussion-between-ypercube-and-dearth)**

Comment: This is likely to be inefficient when a name is repeated a lot, sort of like a "cross join".